# `kCMPhotoError_UnsupportedPixelFormat` when using image created using `ImageRenderer`

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiimage

I'm using `ImageRenderer` to render a SwiftUI view to a `UIImage`. I am able to successfully render a PNG from that using `pngData()`. But if I call `jpegData()` I get the following error:

> writeImageAtIndex:867: *** CMPhotoCompressionSessionAddImage: err = kCMPhotoError_UnsupportedPixelFormat [-16995]    (codec: 'jpeg')

I get the same error in the log if I send the `UIImage` instance to `UIActivityViewController` and choose Messages (and Messages does not show the image in its UI). If I choose Mail, it crashes the process with

> -[MFMailComposeInternalViewController addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:] attachment must not be nil.

The problem seems to be something about the rendered image being incompatible with the JPEG encoder. However, if I share this image using AirDrop, it sends a jpeg file with [perfectly-normal-seeming attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It9Nn.png).

I also tried rendering to a `CGImage` and creating the `UIImage` from that, and I get the same result.

Comment: You probably need to provide a [mre]. For example, this code: https://pastebin.com/2y5N4YiV runs fine and creates the data without issue.

Comment: It's possible this is related to rendering being done inside a `UIActivityItemProvider`. But I can't reproduce with a simple case such as your code, in Simulator or on-device. I didn't have the time to reduce the case further but fortunately I did find a solution. Pixel depth of the rendered view makes me think it's only going to happen on-device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be specific to running on an actual device—in Simulator I was not able to reproduce the issue.

The cause of the "unsupported pixel format" turned out to be a 24-bit color depth in the rendered image, and possibly also the presence of an alpha layer. The jpeg encoder is reported to require 8-bit color depth and no transparency (though I would have expected the `UIImage` implementation to convert the color depth automatically).

The following converts the color depth to 8-bit:

```
extension View {
    @MainActor func uiImageSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: self)

        // jpeg encoder requires that the image not have an alpha layer
        renderer.isOpaque = true

        guard let image = renderer.uiImage else { return nil }

        // jpeg encoder requires an 8-bit color depth (including the encoder used in Mail, Messages, etc.)
        return image.convertedToColorDepth(8)
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func convertedToColorDepth(_ colorDepth: Int) -> UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage else {
            return nil
        }

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)

        guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: cgImage.width, height: cgImage.height, bitsPerComponent: colorDepth, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else {
            return nil
        }

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cgImage.width, height: cgImage.height)
        context.draw(cgImage, in: rect)

        guard let newCGImage = context.makeImage() else {
            return nil
        }

        return UIImage(cgImage: newCGImage)
    }
}
```